# How to handle data from many (over 100) clients with one desktop WPF application clent using MQTT protocol

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, arduino, mqtt

I have an issue with handling data from many MQTT clients that pass it to central controlling application build with C# and WPF.

The clients represent a two axis system (azimuth and elevation angles) and are controlled from main desktop application. So the MAIN app sends the angles to the devices (not necessary that they are the same for all clients) and clients then send back angle values from encoders. The application then shows the data on UI.

I am running Mqtt Mosquitto server broker on the main PC.

The problem is that since there are alot of clients sending back alot of data, the main app has a hard time processing it and so it laggs alot and also just skipps/glitches the angle values.

The mqtt service on C# side is using MQTTnet package, this is how we handle recieved messages:

```
    private Task ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync(MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs arg)
    {
        if (arg.ApplicationMessage?.PayloadSegment is not null)
        {
            Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arg.ApplicationMessage.PayloadSegment));

            OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(this,
                new MqttMessage()
                {
                    Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arg.ApplicationMessage.PayloadSegment),
                    Topic = arg.ApplicationMessage.Topic
                });
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Here is a sample code on the client side that is sending back the angle values. It is called  with dispatcher timer on a predefined tick.

```
    private async Task ReturnCurrentPosition()
    {
        Status.MoveFinished = false;

        if (_mqttService.IsConnected)
        {
            await _mqttService.SendMessageAsync(
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(Status),
                "Suntracker.Move.CurrentPosition");
        }
    }
    
    // constructor where the timer is initialized
    public Constructor ()
    {
       _updateLoopTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
       _updateLoopTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTick);
    }

    // Calls the return current position method on a 50ms tick
    private async void DispatcherTick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ReturnCurrentPosition();
    }
```

The timer is started when we get the message from mqtt with required topic and is stopped when the move is finished.

```
    private async void MqttService_OnMessageReceived(object? sender, MqttMessage e)
    {
        switch (e.Topic)
        {
           case var v when v == $"Suntracker.Move.{SerialNumber}":
                _updateLoopTimer.Start();
                ReceivedMoveMessage(e.Message);
                break;
        }
    }
```

On the main app when we receive the MQTT message this method is called:

```
    private void MqttService_OnMessageReceived(object? sender, MqttMessage e)
    {
        switch (e.Topic)
        {
            case "Suntracker.Move.CurrentPosition":
                ReceivedMoveCurrentPosition(e.Message);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Actual method:

```
     public void ReceivedMoveCurrentPosition(string arduinoStatus)
     {
        if (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DeviceStatusModel>(deviceStatus) is DeviceStatusModel status)
        {
            if (_sunflowerStore.Devices.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SerialNumber == status.SerialNumber) is DeviceStatusModel device)
            {
                device.Status.MoveFinished = status.MoveFinished;
                device.Status.SerialNumber = status.SerialNumber;
                device.Status.ElevationAngle = status.ElevationAngle;
                device.Status.AzimuthAngle = status.AzimuthAngle;
                device.IsOnline = true;
            }
        }
     }
```

The Devices are bound to XAML UI where the values of angles are shown.

So the questions are:

- Is my general arhitectural idea wrong?
- How to solve the bottle neck on the MAIN app side?
- In my opinon this is a simple problem that is used alot in different industries, but i somehow cannot solve it properly.
- Is there a better way of doing this?

The main idea is to control few hundred devices (Arduinos) that control two motors and return the current position from encoder as feedback. This is then visualised on the MAIN application.

For testing purposes i made a different client app also with C# that simulates these Arduino clients. But however i tried somehow all i tried was giving me glitchy data. Even with only like 16 devices.

As shown in sample i used dispatcher timer on the client, i also used normal timer and also was sending data directly as it was computed (but that was sending too much data and was the worse).

Any idea would be much appreciated!

Comment: See Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT  You are using TCP and dropping packets.  TCP is reliable and usually retries each message three times at 5 seconds intervals.  If TCP is dropping messages either the messages have CRC errors or you do not have enough bandwidth.  I like using ping with large message to check bandwidth >ping -t -l 65500 IP  while app is running.  Try a few different IP addresses and see if there are error or long response times.

Comment: It looks like messages are being sent every 50ms (but not clear how many devices would be moving at any one time, or why updates need to be sent so frequently?). I don't think that this is answerable as it stands because we don't know the requirements (simplistic answer would be to send desired values to device and have it respond when it's in the correct position or something went wrong rather than sending frequent updates). If you do need to send messages at this frequency then other detail is needed (e.g. QOS levels, Mosquitto config etc).

Comment: @Brits all of the devices would move at the same time (with slightly different angle values). I want the direct feedback since the main app is visualising the positions with 3D models of the system, but its true maybe 50ms is too fast and i could tone it down a bit. I tried playing with QOS but did not help much, Mosquitto config is the default one.